# Unable to build the app after upgrading the AFNetworking and it failed with Mopub framework

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, afnetworking-3

I have updated the **AFNetworking from 2.3.5 to 4.0.1**. Here while migrating I am getting the error as below mentioned frameworks file is not available.

Note: Here I did not remove the mopub framework. Before this update it works fine and after this update it shows the below error. Any inputs on this.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Project-aztglgwdnwcetrbnpqlmnpnzrbvc/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MoPub.framework/MoPub'
Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: Clean derived data?

Comment: It not worked for me. Tried